# Change default GPU device for Xorg/GDM after PCI Passthrough?

Tags: display, virtualization, xorg, gpu, intel-graphics

The `Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510` device should be used for the Ubuntu host system.

The `NVIDIA Corporation GP107` device had been reserved for KVM usage.

The Ubuntu host system cannot properly use `Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510` to connect to X server. Can we workaround it?

The `sudo systemctl start gdm` command will cause the TTY to flash continuously and hard to use.

sudo cat /etc/default/grub | grep CMDLINE

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity nouveau.runpm=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.modules-load=vfio-pci intel_iommu=on"
```

cat /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf

```
options vfio-pci ids=10de:1c81,10de:0fb9
options vfio-pci disable_vga=1
```

sudo update-grub

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

sudo update-initramfs -u

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
```

systemctl reboot

cat ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log

```
[   876.205] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_3253
[   876.206] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   876.208] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[   876.214] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:1902:1462:7995 rev 6, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[   876.214] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1c81:1462:8c97 rev 161, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   876.214] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   876.214] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
```

lspci -tvnnk

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:190f]
        +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] [10de:1c81]
        |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb9]
        +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510 [8086:1902]
        +-08.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
        +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f]
        +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131]
        +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a]
        +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a102]
        +-1d.0-[02]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]
        +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a143]
        +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121]
        +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170]
        \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123]
```

lspci -nnks 01:00

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] [10de:1c81] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] [1462:8c97]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb9] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [1462:8c97]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

lspci -nnks 00:02

```
00:02.0 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510 [8086:1902] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 510 [1462:7995]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

---

gpu-manager.log:

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:1902
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? no
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1c81
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
        card0-HDMI-A-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Unsupported discrete card vendor: 8086
Nothing to do
```

---

Xorg.0.log:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log
[  2684.239]
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[  2684.244] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2684.246] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  2684.247] Current Operating System: Linux ab350n2 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64
[  2684.247] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic root=UUID=87ad8dee-9975-11e8-a30b-309c230abb92 ro rd.modules-load=vfio-pci intel_iommu=on maybe-ubiquity
[  2684.251] Build Date: 13 April 2018  08:07:36PM
[  2684.253] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[  2684.254] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  2684.258]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2684.258] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2684.265] (==) Log file: "/home/$USER/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Aug 21 11:35:44 2018
[  2684.267] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2684.267] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  2684.267] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  2684.267] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  2684.267] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  2684.267] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  2684.267] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2684.267] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2684.267] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2684.267] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  2684.267] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  2684.267] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2684.267]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2684.267] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2684.267]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2684.267] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2684.267]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2684.267] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2684.267]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2684.267] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2684.267]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2684.267] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  2684.267] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2684.267] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  2684.267] (II) Loader magic: 0x564f402c8020
[  2684.267] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2684.267]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2684.267]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  2684.267]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  2684.267]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  2684.268] (++) using VT number 5

[  2684.269] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_3253
[  2684.270] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2684.270] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[  2684.271] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:1902:1462:7995 rev 6, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[  2684.271] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1c81:1462:8c97 rev 161, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  2684.271] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2684.272] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2684.272] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.272]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  2684.272]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2684.272] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2684.272] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2684.272] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2684.272] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2684.272] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2684.272] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  2684.272] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[  2684.272] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.272]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.15
[  2684.272]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2684.272]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2684.272] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2684.272] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  2684.272] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.272]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[  2684.272]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2684.272]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2684.272] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2684.272] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2684.272] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.272]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[  2684.272]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2684.272]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2684.272] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2684.272] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2684.273] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.273]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[  2684.273]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2684.273]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2684.273] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Fri Apr 21 14:41:17 2017 -0400
[  2684.273] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  2684.273]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[  2684.273]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[  2684.273]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[  2684.273]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[  2684.273]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[  2684.273]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[  2684.273] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  2684.273] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2684.273] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2684.273] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[  2684.391] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
[  2684.391] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  2684.391] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[  2684.391] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2684.391] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2684.391] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2684.391] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.391]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
[  2684.392]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2684.392] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[  2684.392] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  2684.392] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2684.392] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2684.392] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2684.392] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2684.392]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
[  2684.392]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2684.392] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[  2684.392] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
[  2684.392] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  2684.392] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[  2684.392] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  2684.392] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2684.392] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2684.392] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2684.392] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2684.392] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2684.392] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2684.392] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  2684.392] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[  2684.392] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[  2684.392] (EE)
[  2684.392] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
    at http://wiki.x.org
for help.
[  2684.392] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/$USER/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  2684.392] (EE)
[  2684.423] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: There is no error message in your log. Your host is using the NVIDIA graphics card, so passthrough will most likely fail.

Comment: @DanielB, thank you for the quick response.

I have the following changes (updated in first post) applied to the Ubuntu host system to disable the NVIDIA GPU and allow PCI Passthrough. Which additional steps needed for correct PCI Passthrough?

Comment: Maybe I misread. But either way, your snippet of Xorg’s log does not show anything useful. Please provide the complete log and also GDM’s log, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like Xorg is trying to use the NVIDIA card anyway. Did you try [specifying which GPU Xorg should use](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#X_does_not_start_after_enabling_vfio_pci)?

> ### X does not start after enabling vfio_pci
>
> This is related to the host GPU being detected as a secondary GPU, which causes X to fail/crash when it tries to load a driver for the guest GPU. To circumvent this, a Xorg configuration file specifying the BusID for the host GPU is required. The correct BusID can be acquired from lspci or the Xorg log. [Source →](https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2016-August/msg00025.html)
>
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>         Identifier "Intel GPU"
>         Driver "modesetting"
>         BusID  "PCI:0:2:0"
> EndSection
> ```

If `xorg.conf.d` does not exist yet, simply create it.

After that, Xorg should no longer attempt to use the NVIDIA graphics card. The Arch Wiki page lists other issues which you may find interesting as you progress further.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a related issue after installing a second NVIDIA GPU in a desktop computer. When trying to boot, logs would show that gdm (Gnome Display Manager 3) had started, but I only saw a blinking cursor in the top-left corner.

As @Daniel B mentioned in the accepted answer, the fix had to do with the Xorg config file. I was able to use an NVIDIA utility to generate the correct config file.

1. Boot to run level 3 (allows getting a terminal when graphical boot is failing): press <kbd>e</kbd> on the bootloader screen, then add `3` to the end of line for `linuxefi` and start booting with <kbd>ctrl + x</kbd>.
2. Login with your standard username and password.
3. Backup any existing Xorg config: `sudo cp -r /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d.bak`
4. Create the new Xorg config with NVIDIA's tool: `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a`
5. The new config file may not have been placed in the right location. If `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf` or similar exists, make sure it is backed up and then copy the new config file over: `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`  (I had to do this on Fedora 29).
6. Reboot: `sudo reboot`

Note that the paths above correspond to Fedora 29 and may need to be adjusted depending on where your distribution stores those config files.